# Query two tables together, only one record displaying

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am building a polling system and I have a query right now that is supposed to select all of the polls and count all of the votes for each of the polls (which lie in a separate table). So my tables look like:

```
Polls:  
ID  
Title  
Body

Votes:  
ID  
PollID  
Vote  (This value is either 0 or 1)
```

Well the totaling of the votes looks like it is working, the issue is that it is currently only displaying one record.

Currently my query looks like this:

```
SELECT POLLS.ID, 
       POLLS.TITLE, 
       POLLS.BODY, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN VOTES.VOTE = 1 
                  AND VOTES.POLLID = POLLS.ID THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS yay, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN VOTES.VOTE = 0 
                  AND VOTES.POLLID = POLLS.ID THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS nay, 
       FROM     polls, 
       VOTES 
ORDER  BY POLLS.ID
```

Also I am using PHP with Codeigniter.

Comment: Any chance for some sample data?

Comment: What are you grouping by? Group By?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT polls.ID,polls.title,polls.body,
  SUM(case when votes.vote = 1 then 1 else 0 end) AS yay,
  SUM(case when votes.vote = 0 then 1 else 0 end) AS nay,
FROM polls 
JOIN votes ON polls.ID = votes.pollID
  GROUP BY poll.ID, polls.title, polls.body
  ORDER BY polls.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `GROUP BY pollID` the values in the `votes` table:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.title, p.body, v.yay, v.nay
FROM
(
    SELECT PollID,
      SUM(CASE WHEN vote = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS yay,
      SUM(CASE WHEN vote = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS nay,
    FROM votes
    GROUP BY PollID
) v
INNER JOIN Polls p ON v.PollID = p.Id
ORDER BY p.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with:

```
    SELECT polls.ID, polls.title, polls.body,
    SUM(IF(votes.vote = 1, 1, 0)) AS yay, 
    SUM(IF(votes.vote = 0, 1, 0)) AS nay
    FROM polls
    JOIN votes ON (votes.pollID = polls.ID)
    GROUP BY ID, title, body
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is "`GROUP BY`". Use `GROUP BY PollID` while taking sum.